# How can I prevent the delay to updates of ProgressBar when setting the error state

Tags: vb.net, winforms, winapi

I am creating a winforms application and have a ProgressBar control to display progress of a task the application is performing. When this task fails, I want the progress bar to change to a red colour, this part is being done using SendMessage from user32.dll as below:

```
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageW" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
// other code
SendMessage(myProgressbar.Handle, 1040, 2, 0)
```

However when this is done, it appears to cause the progress bar to draw 1 update behind, say if I set the value to 10, it won't update the progress bar, if it then gets set to 20, it will update with the red colour as if the value was 10. I have tried both `Invalidate()`, `Refresh()`, and `Update()` after calling `SendMessage()` and none of those are making the progress bar update correctly.

How can I prevent this delay and allow the progress bar to update properly after setting the error state to change the colour of the progress bar?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but, just FYI, the `Refresh` method simply calls `Invalidate` and `Update`. `Invalidate` tells the control what area to repaint on the next paint - the entire control if called with no argument - and `Update` forces a paint immediately rather than queueing it.

Comment: Don't use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), it makes the code hard to understand. Use named constants instead. Message ID 1040 is `PBM_SETSTATE`, and 2 in its `wParam` is `PBST_ERROR`

Comment: suggested solution in that other question is to call `ProgressBar1.Increment(0)` to get around the buffering bug in the control